# No module System in Pycharm (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, python-import

I am trying to import System module in Pycharm (which should be inbuilt) but the error I am getting is no module names System in PyCharm. I did try to pip install it separately, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: could you provide the could you are trying to run?

Comment: you want `import sys` right?

Comment: Yes import sys as well. It doesn't run.